# Delete all files with the same name but any extension

Tags: vb.net

I have many files in a folder which have the same name but different extensions.  I want to delete all the files who have a name of `abc`, regardless of their extension.  How can this be done in VB.NET?

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?safe=active&source=hp&q=vb.net+delete+files+in+folder&oq=vb.net+delete+file&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l2j0i22i30k1l2.778.2763.0.4091.18.17.0.0.0.0.137.1381.14j3.17.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.17.1379...0i131k1.0.4LREva1hhqI

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks This isn't a tutorial site I'm afraid. You need  seach google for this.

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone is being so negative on this question.  Sure, it's a simple question, but it's a legitimate question which could be useful to others in the future.  Yes, English is clearly not the OP's first language, so help by editing it to clean it up.  It's a straightforward question which doesn't really need an example, but if you think one would help clarify the question, by all means, edit the question to add one.  If you think it's a duplicate, close it as a duplicate, but all the other previous questions I see are regarding all files with the same extension.

Comment: Steven, we are not here do do the homework for others. As i posted on my link, Google helps a much finding hints to solve this problem. I think everyone here helps but no one is a coding service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
Dim sourceDir as String = "here type full path to directory"
'loop trough list of file(s) and delete it
For Each fullPathFile As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "abc.*")
   System.IO.File.Delete(fullPathFile)
Next
```